# Vim change console color when spawn a shell (Mac OS X El Caption)

Tags: vim

When I use Vim, I use **:sh** quite ofter. Sometimes I forgot whether I **spawn a new Shell** or I'm in other Shell.

I'm wondering whether I can **change color of console** when I use :sh in Vim? so that I knew the shell is spawned from Vim.

A picture is worth a thousand words:
[image]

**Span a shell :sh in Vim**
[image]

Comment: What sort of settings are in your environment?  I am using vim under ubuntu, and when using :sh, vim leave a copy of 'VIM_RUNTIME' in my environment.  My bash prompt_command uses this to add a [vimsh] tag to my prompt so I don't forget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieve this on the bash prompt by passing a variable to `bash` and using that in my `~/.bashrc` to check if I'm coming from `vim`.

In my `~/.vimrc`, I have:

```
" Silence shell commands, no need to press ENTER to continue
command! -nargs=+ Silent
\ | execute ':silent !'.<q-args>
\ | execute ':redraw!'

" Silently spawn a shell
command! Bash execute 'Silent INVIM=1 bash'
```

Then in my `~/.bashrc`, I check if `$INVIM` is defined to 1, then I add `(Vim)` to my prompt using `PS1`.

```
if [ "$INVIM" == 1 ]; then
    PS1+='(Vim)'
fi
```

EDIT:

As @Dave mentioned in the comment, Vim already dumps all the environment variables when spawning the shell. So we define the environment variable `INVIM` in `~/.vimrc` itself.

`let $INVIM=1`

Then we don't need `INVIM=1` in `Bash` command definition. So it can be reduced to:

`command! Bash execute 'Silent bash'`

Also, now that `$INVIM` is defined in `vimrc`, it applies to everything, even to any plugins that might spawn the shell.

EDIT2:

Apparently defining a new variable in `vimrc` is also not needed. Vim adds `$VIMRUNTIME` and `$VIM` environment variables to the spawned shell. That can be used in shell's rc file to figure out if it was invoked from within vim.

Comment: This works : -)    But vim ALREADY dumps environment variables in your environment, so use one of those and you won't get caught out if you simply run ':sh'..

Comment: I didn't know that :). Thanks @Dave. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @ronakg, can you change the color of console? so that I can remember I'm from Vim:)

Comment: @JoobLee, you can if the shell supports it. You can do anything once you figure out that the shell was invoked from vim. You should look up if you can change the background/foreground color of your shell from command line.

Answer (score 3):

The `$SHLVL` variable is incremented each time you start a shell inside another shell.

I use the snippet below to display the value of that variable when it's above `1`:

```
export PS1='...$(((SHLVL>1))&&echo $SHLVL" ")...'
```

The rest of my prompt is irrelevant but it looks like this:

[image: $SHLV]